# RingoJS httpserver throws BindException

Tags: javascript, httpserver, ringojs

I've encountered a very weird problem in RingoJS. Consider the following code saved in `main.js`:

```
var {Application} = require("stick");
var {main} = require("ringo/httpserver");
var app = exports.app = new Application;
app.configure("error", "notfound");
if (module === require.main)
    main(module.id);
```

Running `ringo main.js` starts the http server on `http://localhost:8080/` as expected, displaying the default `notfound` page.

Now consider the following code, which is the same as above, except that I hard coded the `if` condition as `true`:

```
var {Application} = require("stick");
var {main} = require("ringo/httpserver");
var app = exports.app = new Application;
app.configure("error", "notfound");
if (true) main(module.id);
```

Running `ringo main.js` starts the http server, but on opening the site it gives me an `error` page instead of the `notfound` page. It says `Wrapped java.net.BindException: Address already in use` and gives me the following stack trace:

```
at ringo/httpserver.js:327 (Server)
at ringo/httpserver.js:428 (init)
at ringo/httpserver.js:506 (main)
at /home/aaditmshah/main.js:5
at ringo/jsgi/connector.js:28 (handleRequest)
```

What's happening? How does the `if` condition affect the server? After all both the conditions express the value `true` (which is the reason why the http server works). This has me abosultely confounded. Is it a bug?

Comment: the request coming in will re-execute your main module in the second version of your script. there's a reason why we write "if (module === require.main)", see the bottom of this page: http://ringojs.org/tutorial/httpserver.md

Comment: @oberhamsi - Isn't `module.exports` memoized and stored in a cache by `require`? AFAIK even if you `require` the same module twice it would only be executed once.

Comment: @oberhamsi - Please would you write your comment as an answer so that I may accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the request coming in will re-execute your main module in the second version of your script. there's a reason why we write "if (module === require.main)", see the bottom of this page: http://ringojs.org/tutorial/httpserver.md